# Can the Glossaries package print unused entries with automake?

Tags: glossaries

I am trying to add a glossary to a book, and ideally would keep the compiling process as simple as possible (i.e., use the automake option), while also being able to just print the entire glossary without having to go back and add \gls{ENTRY} calls in the main text. In other words, this assumption from the [beginner's guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) does *not* apply:

> Most users prefer to have an automatically sorted list that only contains entries that have been used in the document

To illustrate, in the following MWE, only *verse* appears in the glossary; I want *dragon* to appear as well:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[automake,sort=clear]{glossaries}[=v4.49]

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{verse}{name=verse,description={A bit of poetry.}}
\newglossaryentry{dragon}{name=dragon,description={Glaurung’s brood.}}

\begin{document}

Here be dragons in a \gls{verse}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to get dragon to print while leaving automake on? It sounds like \printnoidxglossaries would print the right kind of glossary, but it apparently doesn't work with automake. (In a short document, just adding \gls{dragon} would probably be fine, but for my book I have a rather large glossary, and calling each one in the main text would both be a pain and open the door to accidentally overlooking an entry.)

Comment: there is a `\glsaddall` command. But if you don't use an entry, why would you want it in the glossary?

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect. The terms are not 'used' only in the technical sense of not being called by \gls. The words do appear in the text, often dozens of times. So my options would either be to call each word at the first occurrence (which, as I said, risks my overlooking a word in the glossary), or to go to the effort of calling each instance of every term (which I do not have the time to do). The glossary is custom-made for this book, so there are no superfluous entries.

Comment: well the main point of a package like glossary is to use \gls commands in the text to ensure uniform use of the terms and allow to reformat them if needed. If you want only a list at the end, don't use glossary but a simple description list.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I also wanted to dip my toes into the glossary package. I'm finding that it's not so good as a last-minute add-on, but now I know enough to see how it might be useful to incorporate into future projects from the start.

Comment: Also, cross-referencing descriptive lists doesn't work right, so if I want to link between glossary entries I need something else.